# CSS - how to make a fixed background image over a scrolling image?

Tags: css, html, background, background-image

I have a navigation bar at the top with an image. Ideally, this nav bar image would sit at the top over the background image and disappear when scrolling down. Any way to make this possible (2 background images 1 scrolling the other fixed)

Comment: What's your relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) HTML?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="scroll" class="nav">Scrolling</div>
<div id="fixed" class="nav">Fixed</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    top: 0; 
      left: 0; 
      height: 100px; // position and size only example, adjust to your needs
      width: 100%;
}
#scroll { 
      position: absolute; 
      background: url(yourimage.png); 
      z-index:1;  
 }
#fixed { 
     position: fixed; 
     background: url(your2ndimage.png); 
     z-index:0; 
  }
```

This would make the #fixed background only show after the window has been scrolled down...